# Manipulate index.html in Blazor WASM

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm working on my first Blazor WASM app and I need to programmatically set/change classes for the `<body>` tag which is in `index.html`. For example, setting the light/dark theme is done through setting the appropriate class for the `<body>` tag.

Is this possible only through JS Interop or is there another way to handle it?

Comment: It's not done through <body> or `index.html`, on any SPA. The web page only shows a spinner and loads the Javascript/WASM of the applications. Anything you see is drawn by the application, including styles and theming. If you google for `Blazor Themes` you'll find a lot of results, mainly from component suites that offer their own theme support

Comment: At least one way to change themes is to change the `Layout` or DefaultLayout` values in `App.razor`. Those are normal component parameters and can be bound and *changed* the same way any other parameter can

Comment: I'm using a professionally designed HTML/jQuery template and that's how the designer handled it. He even handled the nav bar through classes in the `<body>` tag. So, using this particular HTML template requires me to manipulate the `<body>` tag classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `body` is outside the Blazor DOM Scope.  However, it's relatively easy with JsInterop.

*site.js* registerted in *index.html* or *_Host.cshtml*.

```js
window.Blazr = {
    setCssClass: function (elementId, css) {
        var link = document.getElementById(elementId);
        link.className = css;
        return true;
    }
}
```

A service:

```cs
public class BlazrInteropLibrary
{
    protected IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; }

    public BlazrInteropLibrary(IJSRuntime jsRuntime)
        => JSRuntime = jsRuntime;

    public ValueTask<bool> SetCssClass(string elementId, string css)
        => JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>("Blazr.setCssClass", elementId, css);
}
```

Registered:

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<BlazrInteropLibrary>();
```

Set the `id` of `<body>` to "blazorBody".

And a simple demo page.

```cs
@page "/"
@inject BlazrInteropLibrary BlazrJs

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />
<div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="ChangeBody">Change</button>
</div>

@code {
    private async Task ChangeBody()
    {
       await BlazrJs.SetCssClass("blazorBody", "black-background");
    }
}
```

Comment: NP - you've helped many others.  It's a version of this - https://shauncurtis.github.io/Building-Blazor-Applications/DynamicCss.html